# Upgrade from ASP.NET 1.1 to ASP.NET 2.0 now web service call fails

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, web-services, asp.net-2.0

I have an ASP.NET application that I've upgraded from version 1.1/Visual Studio 2003 to Visual Studio 2008 (.NET framework 3.5, ASP.NET 2.0).

A call to a web service outside of my application (but inside of our network and firewall) that used to work fine in the old version is now responding with:

> `The request failed with HTTP status 403: Forbidden.`

The web service has not changed. The web service is in my project as a web reference.

The error occurs if I'm running the app from within Visual Studio 2008 or directly from a browser using "*http://localhost.blah.blah*".

Is there a configuration setting I need to make either in my application or in IIS that I didn't have to make before?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you test this in the browser with the *full* url of the web service endpoint? e.g http://servername/mywebservice/service.asmx ?

Comment: yes.. it's fine from the browser.. it only craps out when I call it from within my asp.net 2.0 app...

Comment: Once I asked [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24575177/256431), this was listed as a related question. We haven't seen user175650 for 3 years, but if my answer is correct for here too, I'll be happy to close my question as a duplicate :-)

Answer (score 1):

The response is coming from the server-side and it is telling you authentication failed. So, the first question I'd ask is "how is this thing authenticating?" and walk up that tree.