# ASP.NET Development Server unexpected Authentication required

Tags: asp.net, web-services, visual-studio-2008, aspnet-development-server

I have a localhost port based web page (a web service using the ASP.NET Development Server - MSVS2k8 `WebDev.WebServer.exe`) that works correctly when accessed via a browser (either Chrome 35 or IE 11), but it is currently failing when I access it via `WebClient` (via DotLisp or LinqPad) or MSTest.

This is on a Win8.1 64-bit machine, still using Visual Studio 2008.

I have rebooted but the problem remains, even though this was working earlier today. I have also ran Visual Studio as Administrator and not.

Details:

> Exception: System.Net.WebException
>   Message: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
>   Target: Byte[] DownloadDataInternal(System.Uri, System.Net.WebRequest ByRef)
>   Source: System

Simplified calling code:

```lisp
 (def (get-web-page url)
  (with-dispose
   (wc (WebClient.)
    b (wc.DownloadData url)
    m (MemoryStream. b false)
    s (StreamReader. m))
   s.Peek
   s.ReadToEnd))
```

LinqPad:

```vb
Using wc = New WebClient
  Dim twp = wc.DownloadString("http://localhost:20147/")'TestServers.aspx")
  twp.Dump
End Using
```

(I also have a problem when using Run Test instead of Debug Test, where the attempt to update assemblies for Code Coverage or something related to that is failing in "interesting" ways. But I believe this is unrelated to the above problem, except that attempting to solve this issue may have somehow caused me to change the settings that caused the above issue.)

Comment: This was hard to debug, even once I stopped trying to get the automated testing working, because of the Win8.1 automatic bypass of proxy for `localhost` meant it was a little difficult to get Fiddler to confirm what was different between Chrome and IE hitting the page and the .NET WebClient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how the settings changed, and/or why it was working earlier otherwise, but turning off **NTLM Authentication** fixes the problem.

Specifically, right clicking the web project in the Solution Explorer > Property Pages > Start Options and uncheck NTLM Authentication and click OK.